# How can I "Add Next Occurrence" in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

In Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text there is functionality called "Add Next Occurrence" that selects next occurrence of marked text. The keyboard shortcut for utilizing this function is CMD+D (CTRL+D on Windows and Linux).

This function would select the next occurrence of the text and also add another cursor to the end of the newly selected text.

[image: sublime]

How can I achieve this in Visual Studio for Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported. There is however an open suggestion to the team that you can up-vote if you would like to see this feature in an upcoming release.

Here is the link to the feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351843/multiple-selection-with-the-keyboard.html

Answer (score 9):

The shortcut is: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

(Shift + Option + .)

And its name in the settings is: "Insert next matching caret"

At the moment this answer is the only one working for **Visual Studio** (tested in 8.9). All the others are for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Mine was none by default, thanks for the name "Insert next matching caret"

Answer (score 3):

In Mac, CMD + D will do the job.